# Fixing a child div within its parent regardless of overflow

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am attempting to make a child div sit fixed at the bottom of its parent div relative to the "div window"; i.e. I want the child div to remain fixed at the bottom of the div whether or not the user scrolls.

When there is no content overflow, I am able to accomplish this goal using:

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    color: red;
}

#inner {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: blue;
}
```

The result is this:

[image: Image with no problem]

I run into a problem when the content of `#outer` overflows and the user scrolls:

[image: Overflow using breaks]

[JS Fiddle of Image #2 (overflow using `<br>`)](http://jsfiddle.net/Kgf8a/).

Herein lies my problem: I want `#inner` (the blue box) to remain fixed at the bottom of `#outer` (the red box) regardless of scroll -- an effect similar to using `position:fixed` on a div that has `height:100%`. But I want to achieve the effect using a div that has a set height that is not 100%.

I feel like there is a very simple solution to this, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a second outter `<div>` you can position absolutely within that element instead of the scrolling `<div>`, if the `#outter` div is statically positioned: http://jsfiddle.net/Kgf8a/1/

---

Alternatively, you could look into using `position:sticky`: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

But I don't know what kind of  browser support you'll get for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

on body Tag:

```
<body onLoad="test();">
```

javascript file

```
function test() {
    document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener ("scroll", bottom);   
}
function bottom(){
  var o = document.getElementById("outer");
  var i = document.getElementById("inner");
  i.style.bottom =  - o.scrollTop;
}
```

here is de JSBIN http://jsbin.com/ocijeg/1/edit